# How to log synchronously with winston in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm fairly new to node.js and I've came from C#/Java lands, so I need some help with logging.

Right now I'm writing tests with Selenium, using native bundings and `mocha` as my testing framework. I have a `base-page.js` - base class for all other `Page Objects` which contains basic methods for interactions with the page and a `logInfo(message)` method.
For now, I've decided to go with a `winston` for logging. My logger config looks like this:

```
import winston from 'winston'; 

const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleDateString() 
    + ": " + (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console) ({ 
        timestamp: tsFormat,
        colorize: true }),
    new (winston.transports.File) ({ filename: 'logs.log'})
    ]
});
logger.level = 'silly';
logger.cli();
```

And it works totally fine. The thing is that when I run my test-case all log messages are logged instantly, not as part of a function they are supposed to be logged, at least from C#/Java point of view.

So I want them to be logged only when the execution of action for the page (ie, button click) happens. What can I do here?

**EDIT**: providing code as well as some explanations.
My `base-page.js` methods looks like this:

```
    click(logMessage, locator, ...args) {
      this.logInfo(logMessage);
      //this.driver.findElement() is Selenium related. It returns a promise,
      //so I suppose this is a reason of proper execution of interactions.
      this.driver.findElement(locator.getLocator(...args)).click();
}
```

My `logInfo()` method:

```
    logInfo(logMessage) {
      logger.logInfo(logMessage);
}
```

And `logger` iself is import of `Winston` logger, moved to another file. Configs are provided.

Finally, my tests are calling methods from `base-page.js` by inheritence chain, and i *suppose* that they are called *async too*, but because of promises from `Selenium` it looks like they are synchronous. Only logging shows that they aren't, in fact. So, what can be done here?

**UPDATE**: attempt to bubble up `Promise` from `click()`, returned by

```
this.driver.findElement(locator.getLocator(...args)).click();
```

does not affect overall behaviour.

Comment: It's hard to say without having seen your test script, but maybe you need to return the Promise from your `click` method? i.e. `return this.driver.findElement(locator.getLocator(...args)).click();`

Comment: Thank you for your reply - see my edits on this. My test script just calls wrapper functions for `base-page` in similar fashion of `click()` method.
Can you explain to me, how methods within `click()` are invoked? Because right now my chain is like something: `call A() => call B() & C() `, where `B()` and `C()` are calling `base-page` methods on their own. So what is the order if any?

Comment: @Amrait Dalerian - could you log synchronously to an external file with winston in node.js ?